# How to dynamically call functions in python from a string value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the following library ([dbader/schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule/tree/master)) to schedule tasks and I'm trying to call some of the methods on the class dynamically from string values.

I have an object that comes back from a database that looks like the following:

```json
{
  "scheduled_interval": "wednesday",
  "scheduled_time": "11:00",
  "tags": ["tag1"]
}
```

I am trying to achieve something like the following, but calling the functions programatically whereby the func call in bold is driven by the database value `scheduled_interval`:

schedule.every().**wednesday**.at("11:00").tags(["tag1"])

I tried using `getattr` as can be seen below, but i'm unsure as to how I can chain the calls in a way that doesn't include many nested getattr calls:

```py
def add_to_schedule(task: Task):
    job = schedule.every()
    # Below should be equivalent to schedule.every().wednesday()
    job_1 = getattr(job, task.scheduled_interval)()
    job_2 = getattr(job_1, "at")
    # Below should be equivalent to schedule.every.wednesday().at("11:00")
    job_2(task.scheduled_time)
```

Comment: `f = getattr(schedule.every, "wednesday")` should get you the `wednesday` method of `schedule.every`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend [operator.methodcaller](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) by wrapping it with a function like this:

```
from operator import methodcaller


def chainmethodcaller(obj, calls): 
    for call in calls: 
        obj = methodcaller(*call)(obj)
    return obj
```

And use it like this

```
chainmethodcaller(
    schedule,
    [('every',), ('wednesday',), ('at', '11:00'), ('tags', ["tag1"])]
)
```

Feel free to add a few conditions if you don't want to pass iterables for methods without arguments.